# Running Python on Microsoft Visual Studio to edit .xlsx files into CSV, is it possible with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, windows, csv, openpyxl, xlrd

I use Microsoft Visual Studio as my IDE.

I want to write some python that will take a Microsoft Excel file (.xlsx) and perform some functions with another different CSV file.

From my understanding python cannot work with .xlsx unless you have a module like "xlrd" or "openpyxl"

If I install either one of these modules, will Microsoft Visual Studio also be able to manipulate .xlsx files? Or will I only be able to manipulate .xlsx files within the Python IDLE IDE.

How can I make Microsoft Visual Studio able to run Python that can also handle .xlsx? Or should I give up on Microsoft Visual Studio completely and move to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Visual Studio will be able to manipulate .xlsx files, as long as it uses a version of Python that has access to the openpyxl or xlrd modules.

When you install openpyxl or xlrd, either for Python 2 or Python 3 (presumably you use pip or conda to do this), those modules will be installed to a `site-packages` directory. When you create a Python program that contains an `import openpyxl` or `import xlrd`, when Python reaches those lines it will look in that `site-packages` directory for the requisite module. If Python finds the module, everything is fine, and you now have access to the full functionality of that module, which will allow you to do your thing.

The IDE is not the underlying Python engine itself, it's just a wrapper. Visual Studio, PyCharm, Eclipse, and IDLE are just programs that wrap a Python executable (also called the Python interpreter). The only thing you have to make sure of is, when you install the module (using, for example, `pip install openpyxl`), that pip should be associated with the *same* Python executable that your IDE uses.

You can check what Python interpreter your Visual Studio is using (somewhere in the preferences?). It should also list the version of Python and the location of the `site-packages` directory. If you run pip from your command line with the `-V` flag you'll see something like this (varies depending on how you installed Python):

```
C:\> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: Hi mate,
I have
Anaconda 4.4.0
Python 3.6 (32-bit)
Python 3.6 (64 bit)

any suggestions?
I 'think' I installed the module using pip (90% sure)
the system directory is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
Which I 'think' is in my Site-Packages directories.

*Shift+ Return does not seem to work on Stackoverflow, is there any way to make my comments neater?*

Comment: Well, you'll have to close that 10% uncertainty gap. But it is easy to do. Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages` in Explorer and see if there is a folder with `openpyxl` in the name. Or run `pip install openpyxl`. Those will make sure you *have* installed openpyxl with pip. Then make sure the version of Python pip uses is the same as the version of Python that Visual Studio uses (which *should* both be the Anaconda Python).

Comment: I'm an idiot, I just read that before. Yep, I have installed using pip.

Comment: pip 9.0.1 version

Comment: hmmmm... of my three Environments.. Python 3.6 (64 bit): pip 9.0.1 setuptools (28.8.0) Python 3.6 (32-bit): pip 9.0.1 setuptools (28.8.0) openpyxl Anacdonda 4.4.0: HUGE number of packages! I could make Python 3.6 (32-bit), my default.  But should I be trying to use Anaconda or the 64bit instead? I suppose I would need to install a "openpyxl 64-bit version" if I wanted it to run with the Python 64-bit?

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove some of your Pythons, just pick one and run with it. I'd recommend Anaconda, since it takes care of a lot of headaches for you. When you run "pip install X" it will build module X using whatever version of Python is associated with that pip. So if you wanted a 64-bit version of a module called X, you'd say "<pip-associated-with-64-bit-python> install X" and if you wanted a 32 bit version of X you'd say "<pip-associated-with-32-bit-python> install X".

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted so that others know what answer/information was useful. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)